# Different domains for multiple VM's on host with one WAN IP

Tags: virtual-machine, dns, routing

I've got only one WAN IP address bound to KVM host system and multiple VM's with internal IP's, say, 10.0.0.1/28. On the other hand I have multiple domain names bound to host system WAN IP.

The problem is that I need to somehow route each request to specific VM based on domain name.

Is it possible to solve this issue without buying lots of WAN IP's?

Answer (score 2):

You could install [nginx](http://nginx.org/) or [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) on a VM and pass all external traffic to that VM. They are both capable of forwarding traffic by domain name.

Answer (score 2):

You can use apache web server to do that.It is called [reverse proxying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy).

Simply setup name based virtual hosts and inside setup ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse to forward traffic to appropriate VM behing.

Nice article about it [here](https://calomel.org/apache_proxy.html)

More info can be found [here](http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies) or [here](http://blog.lundscape.com/2009/05/configure-a-reverse-proxy-with-apache/) or [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170703145446/https://blogs.adobe.com/cguerrero/2010/10/27/configuring-a-reverse-proxy-with-apache-that-handles-https-connections/)