# Multiple domains with one public IP?

Tags: virtual-machine, webserver, domain

Hosting multiple domains on seperate servers but only one public IP address with ProxmoxVE...
How can I do this with an easy and quick solution?
The individual servers behind the router should be reachable via ssh, ftp, http, etc..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Different domains for multiple VM's on host with one WAN IP](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40490/different-domains-for-multiple-vms-on-host-with-one-wan-ip)

Comment: Proposed duplicate doesn't have any accepted answers posted yet. Both the answers seem incomplete.

Comment: The answer will probably involve running port forwarding to forward different ports to their respective VM's sshd/ftpd/etc daemons and the `apache` instance should be able to do a load balance using `ProxyPass` to specify the IP's of the VM's.